# AutoLayout - Visual Format Language not working iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I'm trying to learn how to use autolayout and write constraints using the visual format language. for a simple test I have a test view and want it to expand the full size.  So top, bottom, trailing, leading to superview would all be zero.

If I run in iOS 7, it seems to mostly work, but get black bars on the top and bottom of iPhone 5 simulator with no ambiguous layout errors.

In iOS 8, I get ambiguous layout errors.  Can anyone show me where my problem is?

Here's my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    testView = [UIView new];
    testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:testView];

    [self.view needsUpdateConstraints];
}
- (void)updateViewConstraints
{
    [super updateViewConstraints];
    [self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];

    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary =
    NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(testView);
    NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
                            constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[testView]|"
                            options:0
                            metrics:nil
                            views:viewsDictionary];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];

    constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
                   constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[testView]|"
                   options:0
                   metrics:nil
                   views:viewsDictionary];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];
}
```

Thanks!

-- Update - the issue seems to be with    [self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];
If I comment that out, it works fine.  Not sure why though.

Comment: The black bars mean you don't have the 4" launch image.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `[self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints]`.  You are calling `[self.view needsUpdateConstraints]`, which just asks whether `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` has been called.

Comment: I have removed the incorrect instruction to change the name of `updateViewConstraints`.

Comment: the issue seems to be with   [self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints]; in the updateViewContraints method.  specifically for iOS 8.  If I comment that out I don't get ambiguous layout warnings